# Zendesk API - Get notifed of replies

Tags: zendesk-api

We have built a user interface system which is integrated with Zendesk. We have written code as per this [documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/getting-started/zendesk-api-quick-start/) , which creates a case in Zendesk or updates the case as per user interaction on our UI.
However, when a zendesk agent updates the case on Zendesk, we are not sure how our user interface gets updated.
For example - If Zendesk agent replies to a case from zendesk interface, we need to show that update in our UI.
Or if zendesk agent closes the case, then we should be notified to show closure on our User interface.

Polling all the zendesk cases at a very small interval, to find out delta between our records and zendesk records is a very inefficient way and network throtlling too.

Please suggest.

Comment: Webhook >> polling. If you don't need real-time updates, there's the incremental exports API too (i.e. `give me all updates to tickets since <last request>`)

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a Webhook in Zendesk:

https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408839108378-Creating-webhooks-to-interact-with-third-party-systems

Then add the webhook to a trigger, that fires whenever a ticket is updated.

https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408843730458-Triggers-resources

That way you do not have to do time-based polling and can simply push changes to your system.

Answer (score 0):

While everyone has a unique configuration and pattern style, here is what I think is a piece of detailed information that may help you out.

Creating a webhook in Zendesk involves navigating to the "Admin" settings and selecting "API" from the left-hand menu. Then, click the "Webhooks" tab and "Add webhook." You'll need to provide some basic information about the webhook, such as the name, URL, and format for the webhook data.

Once you've created the webhook, you can add it to a trigger by going to the "Triggers" section of the "Business Rules" settings. Create a new trigger or edit an existing one, and add the webhook action to the trigger. You'll need to specify the webhook you want to use and any other data you want to send along with the webhook.

With the webhook added to a trigger, it will fire whenever an update event occurs in Zendesk, and the webhook will send the updated ticket data to your system.

Hope that helps!